# Subclassing UITableViewCell and make a custom cell programmatically

Tags: iphone

I want to make a custom `UITableViewCell` programmatically.

```
- (id)initWithStyle:(UITableViewCellStyle)style reuseIdentifier:(NSString *)reuseIdentifier {

     self = [super initWithStyle:style reuseIdentifier:reuseIdentifier];
     if (self) {

     }

     return self;
}
```

However could I make another initializer without the style-parameter? Or should I just pass nil when I am using the custom cell in the `UITableView-delegate` method? And the reuse Identifier....I do not need to set it in `self.reuseIdentifier = reuseIdentifier` because that is already done by the superclass right?

Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your method CAN look something like this:

```
- (id)init {
    static NSString *cellID = @"rawr";
    self = [super initWithStyle:UITableViewStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:cellID];
    if(self != nil){

    }
    return self;
}
```

As long as you satisfy the methods that the superclass uses then you can create ANY initialiser for any subclass that you want.